# Requests and File cookiejar not working in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, python-requests

So I have a working code that gets data from a website, connects to it if necessary, and save the cookies in a file so they persist each time I launch the code. Here's what the code looks like (obviously I've removed the imports and most of the code to make it more readable)

```
cookiejar_file = 'tmp/cookies.txt'

cj = http.cookiejar.LWPCookieJar(cookiejar_file)
try:
    cj.load(ignore_discard=True)
except:
    pass

s = requests.Session()
s.cookies = cj

# Do stuff, connect if necessary by doing a s.post() on the connect page

cj.save(cookiejar_file, ignore_discard=True)
```

But now that I'm trying to create a much cleaner class doing this job there is a problem: Each time I run the code it has to connect to the website again. So I must be doing something wrong and the cookies are not loaded successfully I guess ?

```
class Parent:

    CookieFile = 'tmp/cookies.txt'

    def __init__(self):
        self.cj = http.cookiejar.LWPCookieJar(Parent.CookieFile)
        self.cj.load()
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.session.cookies = self.cj

    def save_cookies(self):
        self.cj.save(Parent.CookieFile, ignore_discard=True)


class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)

    def main(self):
        # Do stuff, connect if necessary
        self.save_cookies()

a = Child
a.main()
```

Is there a problem with the way I'm doing this ? To me it looks like it should be doing the exact same thing.
The cookie file has successfully been created the first time I executed the code and the cookies change each time I execute it.

Comment: why not self.CookieFile instead of Parent.CookieFile? And you should create an instance of the Child class by doing this a = Child()

Comment: Parent.CookieFile works so that's not the problem. The code works too, I just simplified it here so it's more readable and forgot the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem was simply that I had forgotten the "ignore_discard=True" when I load the Cookiejar.

This works perfectly with Python 3.5.1 and Requests 2.9.1:

```
import requests
import http.cookiejar


class Parent:

    CookieFile = 'tmp/cookies.txt'

    def __init__(self):
        self.cj = http.cookiejar.LWPCookieJar(Parent.CookieFile)
        self.cj.load(ignore_discard=True)
        self.session = requests.Session()
        self.session.cookies = self.cj

    def save_cookies(self):
        self.cj.save(Parent.CookieFile, ignore_discard=True)


class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self)

    def main(self):
        # Do stuff, connect if necessary
        self.save_cookies()

a = Child
a.main()
```